# couchbase server + couchbase lite + couchbase syncgetway + nodejs + raspbarry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I want to develope a CRUD application in nodejs with couchbase lite and couchbase syncgetway. I want to run this node js app on Raspberry-pi.

As I can't install couchbase server on Raspberry-pi so I have to use couchbase lite as data store for my app. As I want to use couchbase syncgetway for sync data on server and Raspberry-pi. I googling much for this but not found any thing.

I already tried steps for install couchbase lite on Raspberry-pi and it is wording fine but I not found any nodejs module which is communicate with couchbaselite. there are only objective-c, java, swift, Android library but not for Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The go-to solution for CouchDB style replication (which Couchbase Lite mostly adheres to) with Javascript is PouchDB -> http://pouchdb.com/

Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some solutions developed natively for javascript as [borrrden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155387/borrrden) suggests, like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) but it has it's own limitations also.

There is another solution if you could install Coucuhbase-lite on Raspberry-pi,
[Coucuhbase-lite hase a REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html), Rest API support which can help you to consume Coucuhbase-lite using Nodejs application.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html

I suggest you to use this REST API because it is more stable than PouchDB then if you could not use that switch to PouchDB, because in official document of PouchDB they announce that this is not completely tested solution with Couchbase and there are some bugs or conflicts, They promise 100% that PouchDB is fully integrated with [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) the ancestor of Couchbase.